# (Zend Framework 1.10) How to use custom DB adapter?

Tags: php, zend-framework

How could I set up custom DB adapter (I will use simple DBSimple) and then use it inside of my model? I don't want to extend my model with Zend_Db_Table, it seems pretty useless for me at the moment.

Sorry for question, but I'm real noob in ZF.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really want to have a *custom adapter* in the ZF sense, you have to extend their `Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract` class and implement all methods within for use with DBSimple. If you do this, you can use the adapter with the entire [`Zend_Db`](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/core/) package and you would also set it up like any other ZF adapter.

If you don't care about compatibility with the `Zend_Db` package, you just use `DBSimple` like you always do. If you want to set it up during your app's bootstrap and you are using `Zend_Application`, either create a custom Resource Plugin or add an `_initDb` method in your `Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap`. See [the chapter on `Zend_Application` in the reference guide](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.application.theory-of-operation.html) for more details on how to do this.

Comment: I don't want to use Zend_Db, so I will use Bootstrap.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

try this, creat a model class

```
function __construct(){
    $this->select = new Zend_Db_Select(Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter());
}
//creat a function to use the db connection created in the __construct function
public function getDatabaseRow(){ 

    $select= $this->select
            ->from('TableName')
             ->where ('columnName =?','$option')

     $query = $select->query(); 
     $rows = $query->fetchAll();

    return $rows;
}
```

}

u can now iterate thru the rows;